# Are there a Code Conventions for Assembly (mainly PIC)?

Tags: assembly, comments, conventions, microcontroller

Are there a Code Conventions for Assembly (mainly PIC)?

Comment: I wouldn't call it offtopic, but my code convention is to use C or C++, not assembler.

Comment: also in agreement with the comments. my convention would be to only use assembly as a last resort of optimization for speed/space.

Comment: I need to reduce the price of the product. C isn't the best choice for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to find the [Assembly Language Style Guide(PDF)](http://www.sourceformat.com/pdf/asm-coding-standard-brown.pdf) which you might be interested in.

Comment: This is the general style, but the comments are pretty lousy (too low-level or imprecise).

Comment: It's a good document to start. But it is as was commented above above

Comment: I've made the same question here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7468/are-there-any-code-conventions-for-assembly and maybe you'd like to answer there too.

Answer (score 6):

When writing assembly, it's pretty helpful and not at all overboard to **Comment Every Line**

Comment: I was just going to say something similar. I have some old assembly from years ago with few comments, and I don't understand any of it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if your programming in assembly or using a c compiler to create the assembly for you, If performance is important don't use a c compiler, write the assembly yourself.

but in general the conventions are to comment every line, use simple subroutines with meaningful pointer names. there are somethings you would comment on the block, ie

```
    start:   movlw   0x24      //  \
             movf    count     //   put 24 into count


    MyCount: decfsz  count     //decrement count and exit if done
             goto    myCount   //do the loop
             goto    exit      //count is done exit
```

this is the typical coding, the first column for the address pointers the next for the command and associated vars you usually define the vars in the header section before the actual program, but that is particular to the assembler you are using. some don't give you the variable pointer option and you have to use a direct memory location. if you look at the commented code coming back out of the disassembler it would look like.

```
    0020  movlw  0x24
    0021  movf   0x25     // 0x25 = memory address of count
    0022  decfsz 0x25
    0023  goto   0x0022   // loop back to 0x22 until count = 0
    0024  goto   0x01FF
```

then you comment it out make sure to group your code use 'nop' s to offset code to good round numbers like start having an address of 20 leaving addresses between 2 and 20 clear for interrupts and the like. depending on the chip I write a lot of code for the 12f675's so that's the model I usually use.

also keep code in simple clear subroutines and there addresses should be nice round numbers leaving blocks of 10 or so nop's between your initial subroutines you can always go back and compress your code later. and always comment your code you cannot comment it enough.

also I usualy put my init routeen as close to the end of memory as posible leaving the maximum space for that actual program.

Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there's anything formal, but reading the coding samples on their website gives you a taste of the usual idioms.  just be aware that there are lots of 'contributions' from many different hobbyists, and they might not be so nice.

also check other projects, most will have ugly code; but you'll find a gem or two.

i never did program on PIC, but liked to read the code.  i vaguely remember a "real time OS" with a really nice and clean execution flow.  don't remember how consistent was the coding style, but i'd start there.

it's better to read most of them and when it's as easy as prose, then you'll find your style

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Jason S -- use a C compiler if at all possible, even if you end up embedding a few lines of assembly language in your ".c" file using the "__asm" keyword.

If you must write entire programs in assembler for the PIC, the recommended function call convention is at 
[PIClist: PIC Paging and PCLATH](http://piclist.org/techref/microchip/pages.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It would really depend on the model of PIC you are using. For example, PIC16s and PIC18s have a lot of assembly examples that can easily be found on the web.

However models like PIC24 and PIC32 are much more geared towards C. Their are a lot of PIC examples in C that can be found on the website for your specific PIC model. These PIC models can still be programmed in Assembly, but their are very few web examples on how to. The best resource for that is in MPLAB under "Help", check the "Help Contents" of whatever Assembler your PIC model uses. This will show you some examples as well as instructions on how to program in PIC assembly and accomplish simple PIC tasks such as defining memory or writing macros.